# What is Floyd's_cycle_finding_algorithm and where can it be used efficiently?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, data-structures

I am trying to understand **Floyd's_cycle_finding_algorithm** but the explanations seem abstract.Can someone help me in undertanding this and whats the basic use ?Does it mean it can be used to find if an array has duplicate elements ?                                          And also java implementation ?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a good entry on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection, it's used for detecting cycles in linked data structures (typically linked lists).